# Determine texture position of neighbouring pixel

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to figure out what value a `varying` have for a neighbouring pixel in a fragment shader?

I'm setting a `varying vec2` in my vertex shader and using it in the fragment shader with `texture2d`. What I'd like to do in the fragment shader is peek at neighbouring values in the texture. I want to look based on the final window coordinates however. For example if I'm at pixel 10, I want to know what texture value I'd get at 11.

That is, I'd like to know what the stepping value is for a particulary varying, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get any information about the varying (or other variable's) values of neibouring fragments. But if you just want to know the rate of change of a value, be it a varying or any other variable (in your case probably the color sampled from the texture), between neighbouring fragments, you can use the [`dFdx` and `dFdy` functions](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/dFdx.xml), which will most probably just do finite differencing under the hood for you (since the hardware knows the values of neighbouring fragments).

Comment: This looks promising, it does what I want at least. The docs are a bit light here, in my case it measures the pixel-based rate of change, but could this be different?

Comment: *"could this be different"* - Do you mean from implementation to implementation? I don't think so. It should always gove you a measure of the rate of change of a value between fragments. Though in which way this is computed is probably implementation-defined But I guess everybody just takes the corresponding value from the invocation of the shader of a neighbouring fragment (which should execute parallel to this invocation, anyway) and computes the difference, though maybe not always the same neighbour (depends on the excution grid, I guess).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y You can also look it up in the GLSL specification. It explains the guarantees and limitations of those functions pretty well.

Comment: The specs do provide more information. I'm a bit unclear about what happens if I turn on multi-sampling (or another sub-pixel-like extension). Does the derivative reflect the final window or the intermediate buffer?  Perhaps this is a different question entirely.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y But a good one indeed, don't know the answer, though.